# How to get DropDownList SelectedValue in Controller in MVC and store it in a variable

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I have dropdownlist,I want to get the selected value from the view and store it in a variable in the controller in order to reuse it.

Here's my code :

**Index.cshtml**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{            

    <table style="text-align: left; width: 900px; height: 160px;" border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
        <tbody>
             <tr>
                <td style="width: 559px;">
                   <select id="select1" name="select1">
                        <option value="1">1 BAL Active</option>
                        <option value="2">2 BAL Actives</option>
                        <option value="3">3 BAL Actives</option>
                        <option value="4">4 BAL Actives</option>
                        <option value="5">5 BAL Actives</option>
                        <option value="6">6 BAL Actives</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Register </button>
}
```

In my Controller I've add a variable to get the selected value :

**Controller.cs**

```
var selectedOption = Request["select1"];
```

I have an error in the controller : 
[image]

Comment: Although this question was closed and visitors are being redirected to an appropriate answer, I think it is useful to note that the original question here stems from a confusion between the role of ApiController and the regular MVC Controller class. You seem to be using a WebAPI ApiController class as opposed to an MVC Controller class. If you use the latter (Controller), your code would be fine. I tested it. Because you are seeking to obtain a value from a visitor via an interactive form on a webpage, stick with the MVC *Controller*. ApiController is for coding a REST-ful interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `@Html.DropDownListFor` for `select1`.

This will bind it to a property in your ViewModel.

For example,

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.select1, m.SelectListOptions)
```

The ViewModel will be available to your Controller methods.

In order to populate the Options for your dropdown, you will need to create a `SelectList` and populate it with `SelectListItems`.

Comment: thanks, where should I create a SelectList and populate it with SelectListItems ?

Comment: @ysfibm You can create it in the Controller and set it on the ViewModel or you can create it inline.  The former is better.

Answer (score 1):

Philip was right. You should utilize the default data-binder to populate the values into your ViewModel. Nonetheless, a faster but not recommended way to read POST data in `ApiController` would be using:-

`HttpContext.Current.Request.FormRequest.Form["select1"]` .

More information about the usage can be found at [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525985(v=vs.90).aspx).

Comment: I've tried this : var selectedOption = HttpContext.Current.Request.FormRequest.Form["select1"]; 

I have an error : the name HttpContext does not exist in the current context

Comment: In that case you're missing the import of `using System.Web` then.